# How To Generate Fusion Charts at runtime using php and ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, combobox, fusioncharts

I need to generate a fusion chart in the page when a user selects the table name from a combobox. Based on value of combobox the chart must be generated on same page while selecting the value in combobox. But the output is coming as "chart" when I click on the value in combobox. The chart is not displaying.

Following is the code I have tried:

CODING FOR **tp.html**

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("chartContainer").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("chartContainer").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","getchart1.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="growth1">growth1</option>

</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="chartContainer"><b>chart will be shown here</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

CODING FOR **getchart1.php**

```
<?php
echo'<script type="text/javascript" src="Charts/FusionCharts.js"></script>';
echo'<script type="text/javascript" src="Charts/prototype.js"></script>';   
// Include the DBConn.php and FusionCharts.php files, so that we can access their variables and functions.
include('Includes/DBConn.php');
include('Includes/FusionCharts.php');

$q =mysql_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("chart", $con);


?>

<?php
// Use the connectToDB() function provided in DBConn.php, and establish the connection between PHP and the World database in our MySQL setup.
$link = connectToDB();

// Form the SQL query which will return the Top 10 Most Populous Countries.
$strQuery = "SELECT * FROM $q";

// Execute the query, or else return the error message.
$result1 = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());

// If we get a valid response - 
if ($result1) {

    // Create the chart's XML string. We can add attributes here to customize our chart.
    $strXML = "<chart caption='CHENNAI-GROWTH YEAR WISE' showValues='0' useRoundEdges='1' palette='3'>";

    while($ors = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

        // Append the names of the countries and their respective populations to the chart's XML string.
        $strXML .= "<set label='".$ors['year']."' value='".$ors['tnos']."' link='F-detailsFrame2-../register/drill1.php?id=".$ors['year']."' />";
    }
}   
// Close the chart's XML string.
$strXML .= "</chart>";  











            // Set the rendering mode to JavaScript
            echo FC_SetRenderer('javascript');

            // Call the renderChart method, which would return the HTML and JavaScript required to generate the chart
            echo renderChart('Charts/Column2D.swf', // Path to chart type
                    '',     // Empty string when using Data String method
                    $strXML,// Variable which has the chart data
                    'chartdiv', // Unique chart ID
                    '660', '400', // Width and height in pixels
                    false,  // Disable debug mode
                    true    // Enable 'Register with JavaScript' (Recommended)
                );


   mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that while using "FusionCharts.php" wrapper to generate chart by calling "renderChart()" PHP function, internally it generated the necessary JavaScript code snippet (as you could see [here](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/FirstChart/FirstChart.html)) and a DIV container, where it renders the chart.

Now, in your code, you are making xmlhttp request on selecting the option, which actually write the HTML+JavaScript code (generated in the requested PHP page) as text inside the DIV "chartContainer" and will not execute the JavaScript code to generate chart SVG stream to plot the graph.

So, instead of trying to render the chart in PHP file, you could simply generate the XML string in PHP file (based on the POST parameters) and send back to the "tp.html" page, where you could render the chart using the XML data came as http response, to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR RESPONDING..i really dont know about ajax and these xmlhhtp requests.. can u actually post the code with changes u think..please..